# Is using the firebase accessToken to identify users server side a secure method?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was wondering if sending the firebase accessToken, which in my case comes from the `currentUser.getIdToken` method, to the server and use it to identify the user is a secure approach.

As I mentioned above I am using the `currentUser.getIdToken` method to get the users accessToken. The accessToken is then being sent to the server which uses firebase's admin SDK to identify the user from his accessToken. More specific I am using the `verifyIdToken` method from as I mentioned earlier the firebase admin SDK.

Server:

```
async function getUserFromAccessToken(accessToken) {
    try {
        var user = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(accessToken);
        return user;
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Client:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true)
```

Let me know if this approach is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That is indeed the recommended way in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens). The token is a [JWT](https://jwt.io/) signed by Firebase and Firebase Admin SDK verifies if the token received is signed by Firebase or not.